# SDTT gives error "The review has no reviewed item specified", but I'm using the 'itemReviewed' property

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets, rich-snippets

I tried `itemReviewed` in different tags but it's not working, and still showing the error:

> The review has no reviewed item specified.

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fasphaltthemes.com scan.

```html
<!-- testimonial start-->
<section class="new_new_testi" itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" >
    <div class="testi_wrap">

        <div class="new_new_testimonial_one">
            <img itemprop="image" src="https://asphaltthemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/lady.jpg" alt="Tar Pro WordPress theme customer testimonial">
        </div>

        <div class="new_new_testimonial_two" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
            <cite itemprop="reviewBody" itemprop="itemReviewed">Thank you for the wonderful customer service you provided! I was anxious about getting my website launched, and had several questions that you answered for me quickly and thoroughly. In a time where quality customer service seems to be a rarity, you stood out. I know that if I have to reach out to you about anything regarding my site in the future, you will be there to assist me almost immediately. THANK YOU!
            </cite>
            <p itemprop="author">- Laura Byrne / <a itemprop="url" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/LauraByrneStudios">Laura Byrne Studios</a></p>    
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
<!-- testimonial END -->

<!-- testimonial start-->
<div class="customer_testimoinal cst_test" itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" >
    <cite itemprop="reviewBody" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemprop="itemReviewed">Love this theme! Very easy to set up and customize, a LOT of great features – especially for the home page. Every request or question I’ve had has been addressed within 24 hours of sending an email, and the responses have been very helpful.</cite>
 <div>
    <img itemprop="image" src="https://asphaltthemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/KcvanHout-300x260-1-1.jpg" alt="Tar Pro WordPress theme customer testimonial">
 </div>
 <p>- <a itemprop="author" itemprop="url" href="https://wordpress.org/support/topic/great-super-responsive-to-requests/">Kelly Vanhout</a></p>
</div>
<!-- testimonial END -->
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two `itemprop` attributes on the same element (which is not allowed), and you are missing the `itemscope` attribute (if you use the `itemtype` attribute):

```html
<cite itemprop="reviewBody" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemprop="itemReviewed">
```

```html
<cite itemprop="reviewBody" itemprop="itemReviewed">
```

What you want instead is something like this:

```html
<div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <!-- an item value; you can use properties (itemprop) inside this 'div' -->
</div>
```

```html
<p itemprop="reviewBody">
  <!-- a text value -->
</p>
```